# How to bring external application window on top?

Tags: vb.net, google-chrome, winapi, dllimport, user32

I have Outlook express always on top and Google chrome behind Outlook. How to bring running Google chrome on top of OutLook express using visual basic?

Following opens a new application but i want existing Google chrome to bring on top?

```
Shell("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe", AppWinStyle.MaximizedFocus)
```

**EDIT:**

[image]

```
Public Class Form1
  Declare Auto Function FindWindow Lib "User32.dll" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr
  Declare Auto Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "User32.dll" (ByVal Hwnd As IntPtr) As Long
  'Private Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As Int32) As Int32
  Declare Auto Function FindWindowEx Lib "User32.dll" (ByVal hwndParent As IntPtr, ByVal hwndChildAfter As IntPtr, ByVal lpszClass As String, ByVal lpszWindow As String) As IntPtr


  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Shell("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe", AppWinStyle.MaximizedFocus)
    Dim Handle As IntPtr = FindWindow("Notepad", Nothing)
    If Handle.Equals(IntPtr.Zero) Then
      End
    End If

    'Dim HandleChildOne As IntPtr = FindWindowEx(Handle, IntPtr.Zero, "Notepad", IntPtr.Zero)
    'If HandleChildOne.Equals(IntPtr.Zero) Then
    'End
    'End If

    Dim Result As Integer = SetForegroundWindow(Handle)
    If Result.Equals(0) Then
      End
    Else
      MsgBox("Above 0: success. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539(v=vs.85).aspx " & Result)
    End If
  End Sub

  Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click
    End
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Not sure if it is the problem but the call is `SetForegroundWindow()` with a lowercase 'g'

Comment: There are a lot of restrictions on which processes can set the foreground window (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539(v=vs.85).aspx) so it may be that you are falling foul of one of these. First though, I would check that a valid handle is being returned by FindWindow() and then check the return from SetForegroundWindow(). Note: One of the restrictions is that the process cannot be being debugged.

Comment: I wonder if this is your real code, given that the first code you posted fails with a hard runtime error. You also appear to completely neglect error checking. Why? Have you contemplated debugging?

Comment: SetForegroundWindow works when the process is the only foreground process. 1) But in my case Outlook, Microsoft Word is foreground process 2) then my application starts as foreground process and then it triggers "other application" to become foreground. 3) in such case how can i be the most foreground process even Outlook, Microsoft word was?

Comment: When i use ` ShowWindow(Handle, 9)` then the only problem is Chrome window size get changed and also position get changed. I do not want to change any position or size when bringing the Chrome window in the foreground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 1 of @Codexer works (Method 2, 3 also included for research later). Note that, Chrome window position/size get unexpectedly modified while applying `ShowWindow(Handle, 9)`

[image]

```
Public Class Form1
  Declare Auto Function FindWindow Lib "User32.dll" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr
  Declare Auto Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "User32.dll" (ByVal Hwnd As IntPtr) As Long
  Declare Auto Function FindWindowEx Lib "User32.dll" (ByVal hwndParent As IntPtr, ByVal hwndChildAfter As IntPtr, ByVal lpszClass As String, ByVal lpszWindow As String) As IntPtr
  Declare Auto Function SetWindowPos Lib "User32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Long, ByVal X As Long, ByVal Y As Long, ByVal cx As Long, ByVal cy As Long, ByVal wFlags As Long)
  Const HWND_TOPMOST = -1
  Const HWND_NOTOPMOST = -2
  Const SWP_NOSIZE = &H1
  Const SWP_NOMOVE = &H2
  Const SWP_NOACTIVATE = &H10
  Const SWP_SHOWWINDOW = &H40

  Declare Auto Function ShowWindow Lib "User32.dll" (handle As IntPtr, nCmdShow As Integer) As Boolean
  Declare Auto Function IsIconic Lib "User32.dll" (handle As IntPtr) As Boolean

  ' Method 1
  Private Sub StartOrShowProcess(ByVal strProcessName As String)
    Try
      Dim handle As IntPtr
      Dim proc As Process() = Process.GetProcessesByName(strProcessName)
      If proc.Count > 0 Then
        For Each procP As Process In proc
          handle = procP.MainWindowHandle
          ' Do we have handle and minimized or not minimized?
          If handle <> 0 Then
            ShowWindow(handle, 9)
            SetForegroundWindow(handle)
          End If

        Next
      Else 'Not running or started...
        Process.Start(strProcessName)
      End If

    Catch ex As Exception
      'Handle your error...
    End Try
  End Sub

  ' Method 2/3
  Private Sub Old()
    '=== Method 1: Target chrome > as new window
    'Shell("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe", AppWinStyle.MaximizedFocus)

    '=== Method 2: Target chrome > Target specific TAB
    Dim Handle As IntPtr = FindWindow(Nothing, "Nieuw tabblad - Google Chrome")
    If Handle.Equals(IntPtr.Zero) Then
      Handle = FindWindow(Nothing, "TITLE... - Google Chrome")
      If Handle.Equals(IntPtr.Zero) Then
        End
      End If
    End If

    ' !!!ShowWindow!!!! help to detect from minmize state
    ShowWindow(Handle, 9)
    Dim Result As Integer = SetForegroundWindow(Handle)
    If Result.Equals(0) Then
      End
    End If
  End Sub

  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.TopMost = True
    StartOrShowProcess("chrome")
  End Sub

  Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click
    End
  End Sub

  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    End
  End Sub
End Class
```